# Chrome Extension - manifest matches read from localstorage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've created a simple extension that stops Chrome autofill for specific IP Addresses. This is working fine, but I want to be able to specify the IP Addresses it should work on.

Currently this is done in the manifest.json using `matches`:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
      "matches": [   
                   "http://192.168.1.100/*",
                   "http://192.168.1.200/*",
                   "http://127.0.0.1/*",
                   "http://localhost/*"
                    ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ],
```

This works fine, but I want to be able to add to that list without having to amend and update the extension each time.

So I was thinking of using localstorage to save the values, but how do I read them back into the manifest json file ?

Thanks

Comment: manifest is immutable. Use [declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) or simply [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) on matching urls in a [webNavigation.onCommitted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) listener.

Comment: Thanks - can you point me to any examples on how to do this ?

Comment: See [example extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) or search for examples using google etc.

Comment: Thanks I have this working.